# How to use pandas to rename rows when they are the same in column A?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is :
[image]

I want to use pandas to rename Hospital when a row with the same value in the Hospital column has a different value in the GeneralRepresentation column. And when a row with the same value in the Hospital column has the same value in the GeneralRepresentation column, no renaming is done for Hospital.

The effect I want is shown below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do need to change the logic, you need the `groupby` `cumcount` the `unique` value

```
g = df.groupby('Hospital')['GeneralRepresentation']
s1 = g.transform(lambda x :x.factorize()[0]+1).astype(str)
s2 = g.transform('nunique')
df['Hospital'] = np.where(s2==1, df['Hospital'], df['Hospital'] + '_' + s1,)
df
  Hospital GeneralRepresentation
0        a                     a
1      b_1                     b
2      b_2                     c
3      c_1                     d
4      c_2                     e
5        d                     f
6        d                     f
```

Answer (score 0):

leverage duplicated to create  boolean. Pass the booleans into `np.where(condition, if condition true, if condition is false)`. cumcount will help generate incremental consecutives  which when turned into strings can be concatenated to original name

```
df['Hospital']=np.where(((df['Hospital'].duplicated(keep=False))&(df['GeneralRepresentation'].duplicated(keep=False))),df['Hospital']+'_'+(df.groupby('Hospital').cumcount()+1).astype(str),df['Hospital'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
dup = ~df.duplicated(keep=False)
g_count = df.groupby("Hospital").cumcount()+1
count = df.groupby("Hospital")['GeneralRepresentation'].transform('count')
df['Hospital'] = np.where((dup) & (count>1), df['Hospital'] + '_' + g_count.astype(str), df['Hospital'])
```

`OUTPUT`

```
  Hospital GeneralRepresentation
0      UMC                     a
1    MGH_1                     b
2    MGH_2                     j
3    NMH_1                     o
4    NMH_2                     a
5      MSH                     d
6      MSH                     d
```