# How to use pandas to rename rows when they are the same in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

According to：

[How to use pandas to rename rows when they are the same in column A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70527337/how-to-use-pandas-to-rename-rows-when-they-are-the-same-in-column-a)

My dataframe is :
[image]

I want to use pandas to rename Hospital when a row with the same value in the Hospital column has a different value in the GeneralRepresentation column. And when a row with the same value in the Hospital column has the same value in the GeneralRepresentation column, no renaming is done for Hospital. And for hospitals without GeneralRepresentation, keep the name of the hospital the same.

The effect I want is shown below:

[image]

When I use Beny's code in  [How to use pandas to rename rows when they are the same in column A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70527337/how-to-use-pandas-to-rename-rows-when-they-are-the-same-in-column-a):

```
g = df.groupby('Hospital')['GeneralRepresentation']
s1 = g.transform(lambda x :x.factorize()[0]+1).astype(str)
s2 = g.transform('nunique')
df['Hospital'] = np.where(s2==1, df['Hospital'], df['Hospital'] + '_' + s1,)
```

The effect is shown below：
[image]

But what I want is for the name of the hospital to remain the same when a hospital does not have a GeneralRepresentation, the effect is like the second picture, how do I modify this code to fulfil my requirement?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean，In my df, there is no such column as test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with missing values, for misisng values is `factorize` set to `-1`, so if add `1` get `0` for last 2 rows, in my solution is replaced `NaN` to empty strings before `groupby` for prevent it:

```
g = df.fillna({'GeneralRepresentation':''}).groupby('Hospital')['GeneralRepresentation']
s1 = g.transform(lambda x :x.factorize()[0]+1).astype(str)
s2 = g.transform('nunique')
df['Hospital'] = np.where(s2==1, df['Hospital'], df['Hospital'] + '_' + s1)
print (df)
  Hospital GeneralRepresentation
0        a                     a
1      b_1                     b
2      b_2                     c
3      c_1                     d
4      c_2                     e
5        d                   NaN
6        t                   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks very much !  It's right.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.select(listof conditions, list of choices, alternative)`

```
a=~(df['GeneralRepresentation'].str.contains('\w'))
b= ((df['GeneralRepresentation'].str.contains('\w'))&(df['Hospital'].duplicated(keep=False))&(df['GeneralRepresentation'].duplicated(keep=False)))

df['Hospital'] np.select([a,b],[df['Hospital']+'_'+(df.groupby('Hospital').cumcount()+1).astype(str),''],df['Hospital'])
```